# Rotating seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to rotate `seaborn.lineplot`, so `height` would be on the `y` axis and weighted PAVD would be on `x`.

```
sns.lineplot(data = df, y = "weightedPAVD", x = "# height", ci = 10, color = "darkgreen")
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if I change x and y, the figure is messed up.

```
sns.lineplot(data = df, x = "weightedPAVD", y = "# height", ci = 10, color = "darkgreen")
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Cant exactly remember, but try passing just the data parameter as a df with just the x&y data - rather than also the x and y params and see what happens.

Comment: Looking at the chart it looks like different data in both charts, why is weightedPAVD up to .16 on the latter but only 0.05 on the first.

Comment: Also the second chart appears to have a LOT more data points

Comment: Thanks @LewisMorris, I have only one data at the moment. Answer below worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With seaborn v0.12+, add `orient="y"` to sort/aggregate/connect over the y variable instead of the x variable.

Comment: BTW, I needed to update seaborn